# find does not find all files

Tags: linux, shell, find

I have the following file/directory structure:

```
tsunami # find .
.
./dir1
./dir1/dirinner
./dir1/dirinner/innerfile
./logs
./messages
```

I am trying to recursively find files and process them using find/exec.

The version of find (comes with busybox) does not allow the use of the discovered file name more than once in the exec command like discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12965400/use-current-filename-multiple-times-in-find-exec). So, I used one of the suggested solutions. So, I re-wrote this:

```
find  * -type f -exec echo {}  +
```

to this:

```
find  * -type f -exec sh -c 'echo $0' {}  +
```

But the new version find the innermost file only, and nothing else.

Here is the output for both:

```
tsunami # find  * -type f -exec echo {}  +
dir1/dirinner/innerfile logs messages
tsunami # find  * -type f -exec sh -c 'echo $0' {}  +
dir1/dirinner/innerfile
```

How do I fix this? I need it to find all files, not just the inner most one.

Comment: Do you understand what "+" does there?

Comment: not really to be honest.I am not an expert at shell scripting.

Comment: Why do you need the `-exec` clause? You will list all files with `find . -type f`.

Comment: the -exec is just to show the problem. In my actual script, the -exec command does something different. I stripped it down to make it easier for people to help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume `echo` is just your guinea pig to run experiments on (sole `find . -type f` does the job of printing file paths).

In my answer I use `find . …` instead of `find * …` – for simplicity. If you have your reasons to use shell globbing then go ahead.

Your issue is because `-exec … {} +` syntax substitutes many paths at once in place of `{}`; so in `-exec sh -c 'echo $0' {} +` the `sh` gets many arguments, but `$0` refers to just one, the rest remain unused.

Use `"$@"`, it means `"$1" "$2" "$3" …`. Because it skips `$0` you need to supply an extra (dummy) argument. For `sh` I use `sh`:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'echo "$@"' sh {} +
```

Also note that if this found too many files for one command line to handle, multiple `sh`-s (thus multiple `echo`-s) would be run.

---

Alternatively instead of `-exec … {} +` use `-exec … \;`:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'echo "$0"' {} \;
```

This will run a separate `sh` for every file, so `$0` is enough.

Another difference is: most `find` implementations require `{}` to be just before `+`, but in case of `\;` this `{}` may be anywhere between `-exec` and `\;`. It means that:

- `-exec foo {} bar +` is invalid;
- `-exec foo {} bar \;` is OK.

This difference doesn't matter in your particular case though.

Comment: oh...I see. You are right. I think best is to use \ instead of +. Your answer helped me search for a better solution.

Comment: this is the final command: find  * -type f -exec sh -c 'echo $0' {} \;

Comment: @hebbo I thought you *deliberately* used `+`…

Comment: either way. Your solution is also good.

Comment: @hebbo Are you going to write your own answer? Or may I include your version in my answer to make it complete?

Comment: You deserve the credit. Add it to your answer.